# How to run python Selenium scripts with Jenkins

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm having few python selenium scripts.

I need to integrate them with Jenkins so that just with one click, the scripts starts execution.

The Jenkins instance has Python installed.

The problem is I'm not sure how they're going to be executed as they contain browser automation scripts.

When we run the same scripts in local, browser instances will be opened and we can see the running of script in browser.

But the jenkins doesn't contain any such facility. (does it? may be I'm not aware. let me know.)

How do I integrate the these python selenium scripts with Jenkins.

How do we run the scripts that opens the browser (either in Jenkins or local) and integrate these scripts with Jenkins?

Comment: you need to connect node machine to your Jenkins server. Where you can see browser execution. then connect both machine through jenkins the create job n execute

Comment: and How do I do that. Could you please suggest any tutorial for me or the keywords to search for that.

Comment: you can refer this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_uyF2x0PB0